# Missing _shape_info in custom Scipy distributions

Tags: scipy, scipy.stats

I am trying to define a custom distribution in Scipy. Let us assume for simplicity that we are looking at the "affine" distribution, i.e. a mix of uniform and triangular.

```
from scipy import stats


class affine_distribution_gen(stats.rv_continuous):
  def _argcheck(self, c):
     return 0 <= c <= 2
  
  def _pdf(self, x, c):
     return (2 - 2 * c) * x + c

  def _cdf(self, x, c):
     return x * (c + x + c * x)
```

I then attempt fitting the parameters to data:

```
affine = affine_distribution_gen(name='affine', a=0, b=1)
stats.fit(affine, data, {'c': (0, 2)})
```

The problem is that I get the following exceptions:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_fit.py in fit(dist, data, bounds, guess, method, optimizer)
    539     try:
--> 540         param_info = dist._param_info()
    541     except AttributeError as e:

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in _param_info(self)
   2921     def _param_info(self):
-> 2922         shape_info = self._shape_info()
   2923         loc_info = _ShapeInfo("loc", False, (-np.inf, np.inf), (False, False))

AttributeError: 'affine_distribution_gen' object has no attribute '_shape_info'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-779300b83040> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 affine = affine_distribution_gen(name='affine', a=0, b=1)
----> 2 stats.fit(affine, data, {'c': (0, 2)})

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_fit.py in fit(dist, data, bounds, guess, method, optimizer)
    543                    "`scipy.stats.fit` because shape information has "
    544                    "not been defined.")
--> 545         raise ValueError(message) from e
    546 
    547     # data input validation

ValueError: Distribution `affine` is not yet supported by `scipy.stats.fit` because shape information has not been defined.
```

The documentation says that the shape is somehow inferred from the signatures of `_cdf` and `_pdf`, and provides no explanation on how to do this manually. How should I proceed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't seen it, there are instructions on how to add a new distribution in the [scipy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/dev/contributor/adding_new.html#adding-a-new-statistics-distribution). Does not seem to be a very refined process.

Following the errors and looking up existing distributions gets you this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure import (
    _ShapeInfo,
)


class affine_distribution_gen(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _argcheck(self, c):
        return 0 <= c <= 2

    def _pdf(self, x, c):
        return (2 - 2 * c) * x + c

    def _cdf(self, x, c):
        return x * (c + x + c * x)

    def _shape_info(self):
        return [_ShapeInfo("c", False, (0, 2), (True, True))]
```

`_ShapeInfo` arguments are the name of the parameter, whether it's an integer (True or False), domain of the parameter, and whether the lower and upper limit are included or not.